# What is reverse inclusion?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm learning about posets for the first time. What does it mean for a collection of sets to be "ordered by reverse inclusion"? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote our ordering by '$\leq$'. Then $A\leq B$ if and only if $A\supseteq B$.